# How to pass current selection to entity browser select view

Tags: 8

I am using an [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) (2.x-dev in Drupal 8) as form widget for a custom entity's entity reference base field. The entity browser is configured

- as a modal display,
- with single widget,
- and no selection display,
- using a view with entity browser bulk select field as widget, and
- to append chosen entities to the current selection of the reference field.

Selecting the entities is working fine. But the entity reference field shall not have any duplicates.

In order to ease selecting of entities without duplicates, I'd like to filter already chosen entities from the entity browser view results. So users will see unselected entities only.

For this purpose, I created a custom views argument_default plugin that exposes the entity browser selection storage as context default argument for the entity ID:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\argument_default;

use Drupal\Core\KeyValueStore\KeyValueStoreExpirableInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\argument_default\ArgumentDefaultPluginBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * The entity browser selection argument default handler.
 *
 * @ViewsArgumentDefault(
 *   id = "entity_browser_selection",
 *   title = @Translation("Entity Browser Selection")
 * )
 */
class EntityBrowserSelection extends ArgumentDefaultPluginBase {

  /**
   * The selection storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\KeyValueStore\KeyValueStoreExpirableInterface
   */
  protected $selectionStorage;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, KeyValueStoreExpirableInterface $selection_storage) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->selectionStorage = $selection_storage;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity_browser.selection_storage')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access() {
    return $this->view->getDisplay()->pluginId === 'entity_browser';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getArgument() {
    $argument = NULL;
    $current_request = $this->view->getRequest();

    // Check if the widget context is available.
    if ($current_request->query->has('uuid')) {
      $uuid = $current_request->query->get('uuid');
      if ($storage = $this->selectionStorage->get($uuid)) {
        if (!empty($storage['selected_entities'])) {
          $argument = $storage['selected_entities'];
        }
      }
    }
    return $argument;
  }

}
```

The issue I face, is that the current selection within the selection storage is always empty, no matter how many entities have been selected at the entity reference field, and even after I complete the modal selection and open the entity browser again.

What do I have to do to have the current selection exposed in the entity browser's selection storage?

Comment: wait so you mean if you have all-ready selected (and saved) an item you don't want the item to show in the modal as a selectable item? 
or do you mean not allow duplicate selecting on the fly  ... or do you mean you want unique data accross all your content  if selected then hide from the view ?

Comment: Both cases. If the entity is new and the modal is used to select related entities, then the selection made shall already be filtered from the entity browser, once clicking the "select" button again (before the entity has been saved). And of course, after it has been saved and is about to be re-edited, the current selection (`#default_value`) needs to be considered too as filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Entity Browser doesn't current pass current default value items field in persistent data, but it's easy to add it.

1) Add persistent data using field_widget_form_alter()

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $context) {
  if (!empty($element['entity_browser'])) {
    $default_value =  $element['entity_browser']['#default_value'];
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($default_value as $entity) {
      $ids[] = $entity->id();
    }
    $element['entity_browser']['#widget_context']['current_ids'] = implode('+', $ids);
  }
}
```

2) Update your selection so that if blank it shows all:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getArgument() {
    $argument = NULL;
    $current_request = $this->view->getRequest();

    // Check if the widget context is available.
    if ($current_request->query->has('uuid')) {
      $uuid = $current_request->query->get('uuid');
      if ($storage = $this->selectionStorage->get($uuid)) {
        if (!empty($storage['widget_context']['current_ids'])) {
          $argument = $storage['widget_context']['current_ids'];
        }
        else {
          $argument = 'all';
        }
      }
    }
    return $argument;
  }
```

3) Make sure you have "exclude" and "allow multiple" checked on your selection.

[image]

By the way, if you update to the latest dev release of entity_browser, you don't need your custom plugin.  There is a new [entity_browser_widget_context](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser/issues/2865928) default value views plugin that is configurable.

I also added [an issue to the entity_browser queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser/issues/3040938) to add this information when in the widget_context.

Comment: I'm looking at doing the same but can't find any documentation, the latest release only adds bundle type as a context it doesn't add the id's of the currently referenced entities. I'm trying to work out how to only show entities in a view that haven't been referenced by the current entity.

Answer (score 2):

I used your default argument class and debugged a little. This is my approach:

The entity browser widget stores selected values in its `current` property, which is filled, when the entity form is opened with an existing entity/selection. The widget also uses AJAX when the modal closes and the `current` property is updated accordingly.

So you can get the selected entity IDs using something like the following in your entity form/form alter:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Element;

// Current selection. Replace 'field_references' with the actual
// name of your field.
$selection = [];
if (isset($form['field_references']['widget']['current'])) {
  $current = $form['time_records']['widget']['current'];
  foreach (Element::children($current) as $key) {
    if (isset($current[$key]['target_id']['#value'])) {
      $selection[] = $current[$key]['target_id']['#value'];
    }
  }
}
```

Another widget property available in the form is the widget context of the used entity browser. You can simply add the current selection to the widget context and use this information with your views default argument (the widget context is updated in the selection storage on each AJAX reload of the widget/form):

```
$form['field_references']['widget']['entity_browser']['#widget_context']['current_selection'] = $selection;
```

Then alter your `EntityBrowserSelection::getArgument()`:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getArgument() {
    $argument = NULL;
    $current_request = $this->view->getRequest();

    // Check if the widget context is available.
    if ($current_request->query->has('uuid')) {
      $uuid = $current_request->query->get('uuid');
      if ($storage = $this->selectionStorage->get($uuid)) {
        if (!empty($storage['widget_context']['current_selection'])) {
          $selection = $storage['widget_context']['current_selection'];
          if (is_string($selection)) {
            $argument = $selection;
          }
          elseif (is_array($selection)) {
            $non_scalar = array_filter($selection, function ($item) {
              return !is_scalar($item);
            });
            if (empty($non_scalar)) {
              // Replace the ',' with '+', if you like to have an
              // OR filter rather than an AND filter.
              $argument = implode(',', $selection);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return $argument;
  }
```

With these changes I was able to filter selected items from my view with a contextual filter for the entity IDs, choosing

- When the filter is not available: Provide a default value, Type "Entity Browser Selection"
- More: Exclude

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the default filter to work but I did have some success doing the following scary-ness:

```
function mymodule_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == "media_entity_browser" && $view->current_display ==
    'entity_browser_1') {
    $request = \Drupal::request();
    $prams = $request->query->all();
    $is_edit = FALSE;
    if (!empty($prams['original_path'])) {
      // testing with "/node/1/edit"
      $check_explode = explode('/', $prams['original_path']);
      if (in_array('edit', $check_explode)) {
        $edit_key = array_search ( 'edit', $check_explode);
        $entity_id_key = $edit_key - 1;
        $entity_id = $check_explode[$entity_id_key];
        $entity_type_key = $edit_key - 2;
        $entity_type = $check_explode[$entity_type_key];
        $selected_ids = [];
        try {
          $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($entity_id);
          // This sucks bacause field name is hardcoded.
          $media_entities = $entity->field_image->referencedEntities();
          if (!empty($media_entities)) {
            foreach ($media_entities as $media_entity) {
              $selected_ids[] = (int) $media_entity->id();
            }
          }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
          // log this.
        }

        $my_results = [];
        // Now need to remove from view.
        if (!empty($selected_ids)) {
          $i = 0;
          foreach ($view->result as $key =>  $item) {
            $id = (int) $item->_entity->id();
            if (!in_array($id, $selected_ids)) {
              $my_results[] = new ResultRow([
                '_entity' => $item->_entity,
                'index' => $i,
                'mid' => $item->_entity->id(),
              ]);
              $i++;
            }
          }
          $view->result = $my_results;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This does work. However, there are quite a few assumptions made... Good thing entity browser allows you to select which view.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to oknate's solution, hook_field_widget_form_alter won't work if the entity browser is being used as part of an inline entity forms complex widget. Instead, you can populate the widget_context as follows (and then grab the widget context in a contextual filter as described by oknate):

```
function mymodule_inline_entity_form_reference_form_alter(&$reference_form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  if ($reference_form['entity_browser']) {
    $entity_array = $form_state->get([
      'inline_entity_form',
      $reference_form['#ief_id'],
      'entities',
    ]);
    $ids = array_map(function($entity_wrapper) {
      return $entity_wrapper['entity']->id();
    }, $entity_array);
    $reference_form['entity_browser']['#widget_context']['current_ids'] = implode('+', $ids);
  }
}
```

Note: this MUST run after entity browser's implementation of the same hook so that the widget_context is already added. It may be necessary to implement hook_module_implements_alter to ensure that your hook is called last:

```
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'inline_entity_form_reference_form_alter') {
    $group = $implementations['mymodule'];
    unset($implementations['mymodule']);
    $implementations['mymodule'] = $group;
  }
}
```