# Where should I include method to pass current selection to entity browser select view?

Tags: views, paragraphs

I'm following this guide https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/277898/56676 which I found very useful. So, I understand where the first function goes, but when it comes to the method `public function getArgument()`, I'm not sure where this function should be included?

Considering that we don't have a custom widget, we are using entity browser in configuration.

So, do we need to create custom widget, plugin or I should add it to existing one?

Comment: Solved - I've created a paragraph named "EntityBrowserSelection" and under the contextual filter I've chose "provide default value" and chose this paragraph.